# How do I store a date time in a local time that can be unambiguously retrieved with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime

I think I understand the fundamentals of it. I would need the local date and time, as well as the UTC offset. Right now I'm using a joda-time DateTime object with the hibernate usertype `@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone")` which works great, except that the timezone stored is the ID, ie "America/Los_Angeles" as opposed to PST/PDT.

The problem then lies during that one hour of overlap in the fall every year during DST. These times cannot be retrieved unambiguously during this period.

Is there any way I can achieve this without manually adding in a column with the hours/minutes offset from UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of Jadira Usertype.

I think you will find that your issue is resolved in usertype 3.0.0.GA.

Regards Chris

Comment: is this an advert? Why not give more information on how this can help?

Comment: Fair enough. The original question is about Jadira Usertype though. The new release also stores the offset from UTC together with the timezone for this type.